# Angular: pass data from service/factory to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-promise

I have a controller where there is `selectPicture` `funtion` used to take a picture and use this picture in a view.

This the code of the function in the controller:

```
$scope.selectPicture = function() {

    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {

        var options = {
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
            correctOrientation: true,
            targetWidth: 720,
        };
        $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageURI) {
            $scope.imageSrc = imageURI;
            $scope.img = imageURI;

        }, function(err) {
            alert(err);
        });

    }, false); // device ready
}; // Select picture
```

The controller code got messy so I wanted to put the logic of the camera in service I did the following `cameraService`:

```
.factory('cameraService', function($cordovaCamera, $ionicPlatform) {

         var options = {
                    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                    correctOrientation: true,
                    targetWidth: 720,
            };

        function takePicture () {
            $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
                var img = $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options);
                return img;

            });

        };

        return {
            takePicture:  takePicture
        };
    });
```

Also I fixed the code in the controller to be like this after I injected the service:

```
 $scope.selectPicture = function() {
            cameraService.takePicture().then(function(imageURI) {
                    $scope.imageSrc = imageURI;
                    $scope.img = imageURI;

                }, function(err) {
                    alert(err);
                });
};
```

But, it seems am not doing it correctly because am getting this error:

> Cannot read property 'then' of undefined at Scope.$scope.selectPicture

Comment: Why is your `deviceready` listener inside the selectPicture function?

Comment: No need for it anymore as i replace it with the  `$ionicPlatform.ready`  in the factory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your service should return the promise because [**`$cordovaCamera.getPicture`**](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/cordova-camera/) does returns promise, there is no need of `$ionicPlatform.ready(function()` method.

**Code**

```
function takePicture () {
   var img = $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options);
   return img;
});
```

Comment: `$ionicPlatform.ready` is a need whenever you use a plugin as mentioned in the docs of ng-cordova

Comment: @AhmadElmoualem you should call ` $scope.selectPicture` from `$ionicPlatform.ready`

Comment: @AhmadElmoualem do upvote if it does helped you.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's because `takePicture` doesn't return a promise (`then` is a promise method). So:

```
// service
function takePicture () {
 return $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options);
};

// controller
$scope.selectPicture = function() {
    cameraService.takePicture().then(function(imageURI) {
        $scope.img = imageURI;
    });
}


$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // initialization?
});
```

Ok, it seems that `getPicture` already returns a promise. So you just need to return it. And since `$scope.selectPicture` is something the user triggers when clicking or tapping, you don't need to call `$ionicPlatform.ready` every time you need to take a picture.

Comment: shouldn't be `return deferred.promise;` ?

Comment: Ooops yes (I've been programming in CoffeeScript too much time!)

Comment: Your answer is correct and in many cases if not all where making `http` calls should be handle this way  but, @Pankaj Parkar is correct about  `$cordovaCamera.getPicture` does returns promise, and all i need to do is to move the ` $ionicPlatform` to the controller.

Comment: @AhmadElmoualem that's correct, `$cordovaCamera.getPicture` already returns a promise (never programmed Cordova). Updated.